# how to handle password expired using Jsch lib in java

Tags: java, jsch

```
try {

    jschSession = jsch.getSession(user.trim(), host.trim(), port);
    jschSession.setPassword(passwd.trim());
    jschSession.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    jschSession.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
    GenericFilesCollector.LOGGER.info("Try to connect to the server " + host + ":" + port + " with user " + user);

    jschSession.setServerAliveInterval(10000);
    jschSession.connect(10000);

    GenericFilesCollector.LOGGER.info(" SSH Connection Ok");


} catch (JSchException e) {

    if (e.getMessage().contains("socket") || e.getMessage().contains("null")) {

        GenericFilesCollector.LOGGER.severe("IP is not reachable for " + nodename + " (" + host + ")");
    }else if (e.getMessage().contains("Connection") && e.getMessage().contains("timed out")) {

        GenericFilesCollector.LOGGER.severe("IP is not reachable for " + nodename + " (" + host + ")");
    } else if (e.getMessage().contains("Auth fail")) {

        GenericFilesCollector.LOGGER
        .severe("Password  Or Username is incorrect for " + nodename + " (" + host + ")");
    }else if (e.getMessage().contains("Connection") && e.getMessage().contains("refused")) {

        GenericFilesCollector.LOGGER.severe("Connection refused for " + nodename + " (" + host + ")");
    }else {
        GenericFilesCollector.LOGGER.severe("Connection timeout for  " + nodename + " (" + host + ")");
    }

}
```

Above is the code. I'm fetching files from some remote nodes using the above code
for the login purpose , but in case if password is expired on some , I can't get exception in my logs.

My concern is how to capture whether password of remote node is expired or not.

Comment: *"I can't get exception in my logs"* - So what do you get? Show us a [JSch log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47411185/850848).

Comment: 2017-11-21 06:29:20 | [INFO] | Try to connect to the server <IP address>:22 with user <username> | [GenericFilesCollector$Collector.run]

2017-11-21 06:29:21 | [INFO] |  SSH Connection Ok | [GenericFilesCollector$Collector.run]

Comment: That's not JSch log file.