# Cannot connect to sftp com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail

Tags: java-8, sftp, jsch

I know this question has been asked several times before and I have tried all of the solutions offered including:

**1) adding these to the sshd_config file**
curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,
ecdh-sha2-nistp256,
ecdh-sha2-nistp384,
ecdh-sha2-nistp521,
diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,
diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,
diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,
diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

**2) updating the jsch-0.1.50.jar to jsch-0.1.54.jar**

**3) restarting the ssh server**

I am running java 8 and using a Jetty server. If anyone has something else I can try to resolve this, I would be very appreciative.

my java code:

```
    public void connect() {
        try {
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            if(!"${company.sftp.password}".equals(password)){
                session = jsch.getSession(username, host);
                session.setPassword(password);
            }
            else {
                jsch.addIdentity(keyPath);
                session = jsch.getSession(username,host);
            }
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.connect();
            logger.info("Connection to {}", host);
            sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
            sftpChannel.connect();
            logger.info("Connected to sftp");
            sftpChannel.cd(path);
            logger.info("Using directory {}", path);
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            logger.error("Cannot connect to sftp", e);
        } catch (SftpException e) {
            logger.error("Problem with sftp connection", e);
        }
}
```

I am not using a password and so the **keypath** points to /home/companyname/.ssh/id_rsa

Comment: Show us [JSch log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47411185/850848).

Comment: I looked at how you set up the JSch logger but It seems to me that will only return whatever message you pass. This is the stacktrace that I get from my logs. 2018-03-14 12:06:48,970 ERROR  [SFTPSender] Cannot connect to sftp
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.receive_kexinit(Session.java:582) ~[jsch-0.1.50.jar:?]
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:320) ~[jsch-0.1.50.jar:?]
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183) ~[jsch-0.1.50.jar:?]

Comment: btw the jar i am using now is .54 and i am still getting the same error

Comment: The code to setup logging is in my answer to tehe question I’ve linked in my previous comment.

Comment: Or check the second part of the answer for a standalone code to redirect specifically JSch logging to a separate log file.

Comment: Hey Martin, i am still trying to get the logger to print to my logs in the server but for now I have managed to get some logs while debugging:                                                                                  aes256-ctr is not available.
aes192-ctr is not available.
aes256-cbc is not available.
aes192-cbc is not available.
aes192-cbc is not available.
CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received

Comment: also this:     kex: server: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

Comment: I will continue to get this logger set up properly

Comment: Fixed it: even though the jce_policy files where present on the environment I removed them and installed the jce_policy-8 version instead.

Comment: Good, please accept that your question is duplicate.