# Connecting to a service through JSch - expected packet type 30, got 34

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I was trying to SSH connect to a layer 3 switch using Java and run some command and receive response using the JSch library (jsch-0.1.54.jar).

It works fine for some switches while on other switches it throws an error.
All the switches I am testing use similar code to what's below.

```
String host="X.X.X.X";
String user="AAA";
String password="PPP";

JSch js = new JSch();
Session session=js.getSession(user, host, 22);
session.setPassword(password);
Properties config = new Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);
session.connect();
```

I am getting following error

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: 2 Protocol error: expected packet type 30, got 34 
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.read(Session.java:1004)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:323)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in the SSH server.

Anyway, packet type 34 is SSH_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST. Try to disable "diffie-hellman" KEXes to prevent JSch from trying it.

```
config.put("kex", "ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521");
```

---

*If this does not help, post [JSch log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47411185/850848).*