# JSch session.openChannel

Tags: jsch

I have this code and when I run it the debug statement 'Open channel in EXEC mode' is being displayed however the openChannel("exec") fails but does not seem to throw an exception as no exceptions are caught within the method but appears in the calling method as an empty exception with no message

```
private int runCommand( Session session, String command ) throws RemoteAccessException {
    log.debug("Execute command [" + command + "]");
    int status = SUCCESS_STATUS;
    ChannelExec channel = null;
    try {
        if ( session != null ) {
            log.debug("Open channel in EXEC mode ");
            channel = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");

            log.debug("Set the command into Channel to be executed");
            channel.setCommand(command);
            channel.setErrStream( System.err);

            log.debug("Set the stream to read result from command");
            InputStream inStream = channel.getInputStream();

            log.debug("Connect the channel which executes the command ");
            channel.connect();
            log.debug("Read return from command");
            while ( true ) {
                byte[] inBytes = new byte[2048];
                while ( inStream.available() > 0) {
                    int i = inStream.read( inBytes, 0 ,2048);
                    if ( i < 0 ) {
                        break;
                    }
                    log.info( new String( inBytes, 0, i));
                }
                if ( channel.isClosed()) {          
                    status = channel.getExitStatus();
                    log.debug("Command completed with exit status [" + status + "]");

                    break;
                }
                Thread.sleep( SLEEP_INTERVAL);
            }   
        }
        else {
            throw new RemoteAccessException( "Unable to run a command as the Session has not been created");
        }
    }
    catch ( IOException ioe ) {
        throw new RemoteAccessException("Remote Command failed: " + ioe.getMessage());
    }
    catch ( JSchException je ) {
        throw new RemoteAccessException("Remote Command failed: " + je.getMessage());
    }
    catch ( InterruptedException ie ) {
        throw new RemoteAccessException("Remote Command has been interrupted");
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) {
        log.debug("RunCommand failure: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        channel.disconnect();
    }
    return status;
}
```

Comment: *"appears in the calling method as an empty exception with no message"* - No idea what you mean by that.

Comment: Also we need [mcve]. + [JSch log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47411185/850848) might be useful as well.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the exact exception that you're getting, including the stacktrace. Don't paraphrase error messages.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for being late getting back but I have now resolved the problem which was being created elsewhere in the code