# Unable to establish connection to unix server using Jsch and private key from IPSwitch client

Tags: java, rsa, jsch, private-key, public-key

I am trying to establish a connection to a Unix server and put/get files using SFTP. I am using JCraft's Jsch 0.1.53 and RSA token based authentication. No password.

I have generated the private key and public keys using IPSwitch software and have configured the public key for the user in the Unix server.

I am using the private key generated by the IPSwitch in my Java program which in turn uses JSch.

IPSwitch's Store.ini file looks like

```
[____Item____0]
____ItemName____=auto
PublicKey=C:\ClientKeyStore\Pub203E.tmp
Pass=_y**************************NyYbpT
PrivateKey=C:\ClientKeyStore\Pri203F.tmp
[__CONFIG__]
Count=1
```

private key looks like,

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----

MIIFHzBJB*******************************

B**************************************B

************1on4MNDZfTgQ==

-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

There are lots of examples in stackoverflow and elsewhere. I tried it but I am hitting *com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth* cancel.

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.UserInfo;


public class UnixUtilities {

public void unixConnectionUsingKey(String username, String hostIPAddress, int portNumber) throws JSchException {

    JSch jsch = new JSch();

    jsch.addIdentity("src/main/resources/keys/id_rsa");

    Session session = jsch.getSession(username, hostIPAddress, portNumber);

    session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");

    UserInfo userinfo = new MyUserInfo();
    session.setUserInfo(userinfo);

    session.connect();

    Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
}

}

class MyUserInfo implements UserInfo {
String password = null;

@Override
public String getPassphrase() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String passwd) {
    password = passwd;
}

@Override
public boolean promptPassphrase(String message) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean promptPassword(String message) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean promptYesNo(String message) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void showMessage(String message) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

I am hitting

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth cancel
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:511)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
```

When I use only *publickey* instead of *publickey,keyboard-interactive,password* as *PreferredAuthentications*, I am hitting,

```
  com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:512)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
```

Also, if I ignore the below 2 lines, i.e., if I comment the below 2 lines

```
UserInfo userinfo = new MyUserInfo();

session.setUserInfo(userinfo);
```

I am hitting,

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: USERAUTH fail
at com.jcraft.jsch.UserAuthPublicKey.start(UserAuthPublicKey.java:119)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:463)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
```

The Jsch log is as follows,

```
    Connecting to ***.***.**.*** port ****

    Connection established

    Remote version string: SSH-2.0-6.4.0.370 SSH Tectia Server

    Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.53

    CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256

    aes256-ctr is not available.

    aes192-ctr is not available.

    aes256-cbc is not available.

    aes192-cbc is not available.

    CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521

    CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521

    SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent

    SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received

    kex: server: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256@ssh.com,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256

    kex: server: ssh-rsa,ssh-rsa-sha256@ssh.com

    kex: server: aes128-cbc

    kex: server: aes128-cbc

    kex: server: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha256-2@ssh.com,hmac-sha224@ssh.com,hmac-sha256@ssh.com,hmac-sha384@ssh.com,hmac-sha512@ssh.com

    kex: server: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha256-2@ssh.com,hmac-sha224@ssh.com,hmac-sha256@ssh.com,hmac-sha384@ssh.com,hmac-sha512@ssh.com

    kex: server: none,zlib

    kex: server: none,zlib

    kex: server: 

    kex: server: 

    kex: client: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

    kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521

    kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc

    kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc

    kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96

    kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96

    kex: client: none

    kex: client: none

    kex: client: 

    kex: client: 

    kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-sha1 none

    kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-sha1 none

    SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent

    expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY

    ssh_rsa_verify: signature true

    Permanently added '***.***.**.***' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.

    SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent

    SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received

    SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent

    SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received

    Authentications that can continue: publickey

    Next authentication method: publickey

    Disconnecting from ***.***.**.*** port ****
```

I am using the same key that was generated by IPSwitch and have named it as id_rsa in my eclipse. Is the private key generated out of IPSwitch supposed to work for JSch as well?

When I connect via IPSwitch, it works all fine. Could you please help me here?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the public key need to go into ~/.ssh/authorized_keys ?

Comment: Although I can't cross-verify this due to limited access, I believe the public key is already placed in there. That's how IPSwitch software is able to establish connection and SFTP files?

Comment: What do you mean by *"RSA token based authentication"*? Your code does simple public key authentication + Show us [JSch log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47411185/850848).

Comment: I'm not familiar with IPSwitch.  ssh, scp (and psftp for that matter), connect using sshd of some flavor on the server.  The programs themselves don't require the key be there, the ssh/sshd connection they rely on does and the sshd looks for the public key in authorized_keys.

Comment: @Duston *"The programs themselves don't require the key be there"* is rather unclear and potentially confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on how to generate JSch logs Martin. I have added the log to the post as it was long for a comment.

Looks like Jsch continues to public key authentication but disconnects all of a sudden. Please refer to the last 3 lines of the log.

Comment: Also I was trying to monitor the traffic at server side every time I made an attempt to connect using my Jsch code, it kept saying 'key exchange failed'.

Comment: And I must be using the right private key. Because when I alter the private key, I get invalid privatekey exception.

com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: invalid privatekey: [B@3f093abe
 at com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.load(KeyPair.java:747)
 at com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.load(KeyPair.java:561)
 at com.jcraft.jsch.IdentityFile.newInstance(IdentityFile.java:40)
 at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.addIdentity(JSch.java:407)
 at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.addIdentity(JSch.java:367)

Answer (score 0):

To provide a *passphrase* for an *encrypted private key*, you need to implement [`UserInfo.promptPassphrase`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/UserInfo.html#promptPassphrase-java.lang.String-) and [`UserInfo.getPassphrase`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/UserInfo.html#getPassphrase--), not `UserInfo.getPassword` and `UserInfo.promptPassword`.

```
@Override
public boolean promptPassphrase(String message) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public String getPassphrase() {
    return password;
}
```

*(and for a consistency, you should rename your `password` field to `passphrase`).*

Comment: No luck. I renamed password to passphrase. Removed setPassword method. Made getPassword to return null. Made getPassphrase method to return passphrase. Did not help. 
Note: I did not use any passphrase while creating the keys. So assigning passphrase as null should be valid.

Comment: The keys says `BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY` -- What means it **has a passphrase**.  I do not know IPSwitch. But possibly it autogenerates the passphrase. Isn't it this? `Pass=_y**************************NyYbpT`. --- If you did not intend to encrypt the key, you can simply remove the passphrase and you won't need to implement the `UserInfo`.

Comment: Well actually that 'Pass' is just there in the IPSwitch's .ini file. I am not using it in my Java JSch code at all. Now that you told me to ignore the UserInfo, I am hitting 'com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: USERAUTH fail' exception. Also I tried to use this Pass as passphrase and passed it as the second argument like passphrase.getbytes() in addIdentity method. It did not work. Same Auth fail exception. I tried to return the passphrase from getPassphrase() method of UserInfo i.e., instead of passphrase = nulll; I assigned the passpharse and it was returned by getPassphrase(). It didn't work too

Comment: OK, start by trying that key in any SSH/SFTP client other than IPSwitch. E.g. in PuTTY - Try to import the key into PuTTY's PuTTYgen. Until you are able to do that, there's no point trying it with JSch.

Comment: Yes. I tried to connect to this SFTP server through one more unix server. Used ssh coomand like 'ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa username@***.***.**.***' and it asked me to enter the passphrase like 'Enter passphrase for key'. I can't enter the passphrase because I dont know what it is. It could be that Pass from .ini file but it does not seem to work here.I looked into how IPSwitch generates keys. It does not asks for the passphrase explicitly. Looks like it auto-generates one. So we should be trying to generate keys from a different method say SSH-Keygen and try to use it for JSch?

Comment: That would definitely work. Or I would expect IPSwitch to allow exporting the key somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  Martin Prikryl and the community for being with this while I solve this problem.

It was simple. As Martin mention one of his comment, I just had to generate one more set of keys using another tool like SSH-Keygen and use it instead. I used a software called VANDYKE SecureCRT to generate one more set of keys and it works just fine with JSch. Looks like IPSwitch does something while generating keys which does not seem to work with JSch. It could be that 'Pass' which is available in the config file of IPSwitch, which is specific to IPSwitch.

Code is as follows,

```
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        jsch.addIdentity(privateKeyPath);


        JSch.setLogger(new com.jcraft.jsch.Logger() {
            Path path = Paths.get("target/jsch.log");
            @Override
            public boolean isEnabled(int level){
                return true;
            }
            public void log(int level, String message){
                try {
                    StandardOpenOption option =
                       !Files.exists(path) ? StandardOpenOption.CREATE : StandardOpenOption.APPEND;
                    Files.write(path, java.util.Arrays.asList(message), option);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println(message);
                }
            }
        });

        Session session = jsch.getSession(username, host, port);

        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey");
        session.connect();
```

Here the setlogger method helps you with good logs. If you dont want it, you can ignore that step.