# JSch session hangs when attempting to get connection

Tags: jsch

I am using com.jcraft.jsch version 0.1.55 and connecting to a number of Linux servers, one at a time.  Some server connections are successful, while others are not.

Ostensibly the code in the servers is identical. I need to find out why the different behaviour.

Client code. Set up

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = jsch.getSession("username", ip_address, 22);
session.setPassword("password");
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking","no");
session.connect()
```

Hangs on calling UserAuthGSSAPIWithMIC.start()

Working flow:

```
Session.start()
line 22 super.start(session) sets buf[5] = 51
line 25 this.buf.putByte((byte)50) sets buf[5] = 50
flow continues to line 39 this.buf = session.read(this.buf) which returns
and has set buf[5] to 51 forcing the auth to move on the next auth method.
Eventually succeeds using the password method
```

Broken flow:

```
Session.start()
super.start() sets buf[5] = 51
this.buf.putByte((byte)50) sets buf[5] = 50
flow continues to line 39 this.buf = session.read(this.buf) which returns 
and has set buf[5] to 60 which sends the code to create a new context, 
part of which calls oid.equals() which hangs on line 160 -
return this.oid.equals.((Object) ((Oid) other).oid);
```

There are no log messages in this part of the code, so no information about what the code is doing.

I can make the problem go away by setting session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "password");

I want to know why the code is hanging on the UserAuthGSSAPIWithMIC on some servers but not others. Also how I can get some informative logging information.

Comment: It probably happens for servers that do support Kerberos -- JSch log file may show more: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47411185/850848

Comment: Thanks @MartinPrikryl. JSch shows 'INFO: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic' then hangs for a while. Eventually 'Process finished with exit code -1, Kerberos username [myusername].  Confirms what I had debugged. Unfortunately the server logs don't report what's happening. I'll continue to dig and post any findings.

Comment: JSch tries to initialize Kerberos. You can skip that by setting `PreferredAuthentications` (as you do already).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl   Yup. I did that and it works around the problem. Incidentally, have you noticed that the timeout value does not work, Setting the timeout to 12 (msecs) and the JSch code returns immediately (or after 12 msecs).  But if you set a timeout value >12 the JSch code hangs (infinitely), until presumably the socket timeout expires. I eventually get 'Process finished with exit code -1, Kerberos username [<myusername>].

Comment: I'm not surprised that the timeout does not cause the code to break a synchronous Kerberos initialization.

Comment: Ah! That's why.  Thanks Martin