# Not able to connect to sftp using jcraft JSch with camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, sftp, talend, jsch

I am trying to connect to SFTP sftp server through camel route. But I am getting some error related to jCraft Jsch exception :

Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:512)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.connect(SftpOperations.java:124)

Here my code to read inside my xml settings.

```
.recipientList(simple("sftp://${exchangeProperty.x_username}@${exchangeProperty.x_host}:${exchangeProperty.x_port}/${exchangeProperty.folder}"
+ "?privateKeyFile=${exchangeProperty.privatekey}"
+ "&privateKeyPassphrase=${exchangeProperty.keypassphrase}"
+ "&password=${exchangeProperty.password}"
+ "&preferredAuthentications=publickey"
+ "&passiveMode=${exchangeProperty.mode}"
+ "&connectTimeout=${exchangeProperty.timeout_connect}"
+ "&soTimeout=${exchangeProperty.timeout_socket}"
+ "&timeout=${exchangeProperty.timeout_read}"
+ "&tempFileName=inprogress.${file:name}.filepart"
+ "&stepwise=${exchangeProperty.stepwise}"
+ "&fastExistsCheck=${exchangeProperty.fastExistsCheck}"
+ "&disconnect=true"
)).cacheSize(-1)
```

Comment: Are you sure you need both key and password? How do you authenticate with commandline/GUI SFTP client?  + Double check any special characters in your credentials that may need escaping in URL.

Comment: I authenticate with my key. Nothing in my credentials needs escaping.

Comment: to be able find the problem, you need to provide Jsch log output. See Martins answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47411796/2290153 how to do it.