# SSH connection not working only on android device

Tags: java, android, ssh, jsch

I'm just trying to make a simple ssh connection from my android device, this code works fine from my Android Studio but when I run it on my Android device does not work. it is not able to find the host at all.

I think it has something to do with network but I don't know what. I check all the settings and everything looks normal, the device I want to reach is in my home network and from my router I can see all the devices with proper names and all are reachable, I can ping all of them included my Android device from where I want to run this code.

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    String host, username, password, command;
    Integer port;
    TextView shellOutput;
    
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        
        shellOutput = findViewById(R.id.toShowMessage);
        host = intent.getStringExtra("host");
        port = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("port"));
        username = intent.getStringExtra("username");
        password = intent.getStringExtra("password");
        command = intent.getStringExtra("command");
    
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
    
                    executeSSHCommand(host, port, username, password, command);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                   ex.printStackTrace();
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.Activity2), R.string.connection_test,
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    
    
    }
    
    public void executeSSHCommand(String host, int port, String username, String password, String command) {
    
        try {
    
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession(username, host, port);
            session.setPassword(password);
    
            // Avoid asking for key confirmation
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(prop);
    
            session.connect();
    
            // SSH Channel
            ChannelExec channelssh = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            channelssh.setOutputStream(baos);
    
            // Execute command
            channelssh.setCommand(command);
    
            channelssh.connect();
    
    
            while (true) {
                if (channelssh.isClosed()) {
                    break;
                }
            }
    
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.Activity2), R.string.connection_success,
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            
            shellOutput.setText(baos.toString());
            channelssh.disconnect();
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            // show the error in the UI
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.Activity2), R.string.connection_failed + "//" + e.getMessage(),
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: *"Does not work"* does not work as a problem description. What happens? Do you get any error? Does the code hang? Or does it work incorrectly somehow? [JSch log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47411185/850848) might be useful.

Comment: as I said in the description it is "NOT ABLE TO FIND THE HOST " that im trying to reach, that is what the JSchException says

Comment: *Exact* error message please. + Log file.